# How can Windows performance counter data be saved directly to SQL Server tables?

Tags: windows, sql-server, performance-monitor

I would like to log data from a given set of Windows performance counters directly to tables SQL Server.  Does Windows provide a way to do this without writing a custom application to do so?

If so, are there any serious issues with doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Here's a resume based on [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1722/collecting-performance-counters-and-using-sql-server-to-analyze-the-data/) article.

## Select the counters you want to analyze

Export all counters on local machine to a local folder.

```
typeperf -q  > counters.txt
```

Edit the file exported and leave only the counters you want to sample. I left the two below:

```
\Processor(*)\% Processor Time
\Memory\Pages/sec
```

## Collect Data

Here you will collect the data you want to analyze using logman.

Create a collection.

```
logman create counter MyCollection -s %computername% -cf counters.txt
```

Start Logging

```
logman MyCollection start
```

Once you have collected a representative sample, stop coolection.

```
logman MyCollection stop
```

By default on Vista and Windows 2008 servers, your performance monitor counters will be stored in %systemdrive%\PerfLogs\Admin
and will be named after your collection name (in our case they will be called MyCollection.blg
So, you need to go to this folder.

```
cd %systemdrive%\PerfLogs\Admin
```

## Load to SQL Server

Create a ODBC datasource. [Warning](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/30fae494-592a-4d96-86e8-ed2bd7120f5c/call-to-sqlexecdirect-failed-with-1?forum=sqldataaccess): SQL Server Native Client cannot be used with perfmon. Perfmon is a Windows tool that can only be used with DSNs that use the MDAC SQLODBC driver included with Windows.

I created an ODBC datasource named relogDSN. ServerName is the name of the server which I collected the data on. This name will be written to the SQL Server table DisplayToID that is created and I can query on it when I want to look at my counters.

```
relog MyCollection_000001.blg -f SQL -o SQL:relogDSN!ServerName
```

## Analyzing Data

Your counters will be saved to the tables CounterDetails, CounterData and DisplayToID, here's a SQL query as an example.

```
SELECT MachineName,
   CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), CounterDateTime)) as [Date],
   AVG(CounterValue) as Average,
   MIN(CounterValue) as Minimum,
   MAX(CounterValue) as Maximum
FROM CounterDetails
   JOIN CounterData ON CounterData.CounterID = CounterDetails.CounterID
   JOIN DisplayToID ON DisplayToID.GUID = CounterData.GUID
GROUP BY MachineName,
   CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), CounterDateTime))
```

Comment: Can you summarize the information from the link in your answer in case the page disappears?

Answer (score 0):

there is no built-in way in Windows to write the PerfCounters to a SQL Database. You must code a tool which does this.